# Getting elasticsearch "can not run as root" error after upgrading from SonarQube 6.5 to 6.6. Nothing else changed

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube, runtimeexception, sonarqube-ops

Getting elasticsearch "can not run as root" error after upgrading from SonarQube 6.5 to 6.6. Nothing else changed.

CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:106) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:195) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:342) [elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132) [elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123) [elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:67) [elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) [elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) [elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) [elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
2017.10.20 11:59:14 WARN  es[][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:67) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:106) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:195) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:342) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: Check the user that is running the software. See [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/why-is-it-elasticsearch-is-not-allowed-to-run-as-root/60413/6) article.

Comment: please take a look at https://michalwegrzyn.wordpress.com/2016/07/14/do-not-run-sonar-as-root/

Comment: look at this solution, it may work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72376209/5659278

Answer (score 41):

I also experienced this problem, running SonarQube, as root, on Centos 7, not inside docker.  As mentioned in previous comments, the problem comes from SonarQube upgrading ElasticSearch, and the new version no longer allows itself to be run as root.

In my environment the fix was easy enough: I had already created a user ("sonar") and group ("sonar") to "own" the sonarqube files.  Since my SonarQube process had been running as root, it had left the logs and temp files owned by root.
1. I stopped the service. 
2. Reassigned all the ownserships ("chown -R sonar:sonar /opt/sonarqube-6.6")
3. Changed `#RUN_AS_USER=` in `/opt/sonarqube-6.6/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh` line 48 to `RUN_AS_USER=sonar` and both the sonarqube service and its elasticsearch service restarted without further problems.  I was left having to go to `http://<sonarhost:port>/setup` to upgrade the database and from there everything worked fine.

Comment: This answer should be accepted by the OP, @RayeRaskin. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/47733598/766786 for the reason why.

Comment: works perfectly, if you don't have a sonar user simply add `useradd sonar` to create one before step 2

Answer (score 2):

Change in systemd:

```
User=sonar
Group=sonar
```

and change all source and 
`#RUN_AS_USER=sonar`
It will run. It seem the error in enviroment when run in root then su to sonar

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, do some changes in my sonar service file and it start working. below is my sonar service file

```
[Unit]
Description=SonarQube service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
#Type=simple
User=sonar
Group=sonar
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop
StandardOutput=syslog
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitNPROC=8192
#TimeoutStartSec=5
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also follow change the home directory of sonar user

```
$ usermod -d /opt/sonarqube sonar
```

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded sonarqube-6.5 and tried setting up a new user "sonar" but still es fails for me with the same reason - Ubuntu 16.4.