# Can't run Sonar Server caused by Elasticsearch cannot running as root

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, sonarqube

I'm trying to install SonarQube : i ve followed those steps :

[Setting up SOnarQube Tuto : here](http://dev.mamikon.net/installing-sonarqube-on-ubuntu/)

To summarize it :

- Downloading Sonar and moving it to `/opt/sonar`
- adding those coonfig steps to `/opt/sonar/conf/sonar.properties`  :

  sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
  sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance

**and**

```
sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1
sonar.web.context=/sonar
sonar.web.port=9000
```

- implementing **sonar** as a service:

sudo cp /opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh /etc/init.d/sonar

```
sudo gedit /etc/init.d/sonar
```

**Insert two new lines:**

```
SONAR_HOME=/opt/sonar
PLATFORM=linux-x86-64
Modify the following lines:

WRAPPER_CMD="${SONAR_HOME}/bin/${PLATFORM}/wrapper"
WRAPPER_CONF="${SONAR_HOME}/conf/wrapper.conf"
```

**...**

```
PIDDIR="/var/run"
Register as a Linux service:

sudo update-rc.d -f sonar remove
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/sonar
sudo update-rc.d sonar defaults
```

After those steps : i ve tried to run Sonar from : `localhost:9000/sonar` and after executing : `sudo /etc/init.d/sonar start`
`
Strangely , it didsn't run .

SO when i run `sudo /etc/init.d/sonar status , i discover that it goes steps after few seconds , and it throws some error in it log file , like the following :

**es.log:**

```
2017.12.09 18:05:14 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap] Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:106) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:195) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:342) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:70) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
2017.12.09 18:05:14 WARN  es[][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:106) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:195) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:342) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    ... 6 more
```

**Any suggestions ??**

Comment: I don't know how Sonar starts elasticsearch but for sure elasticsearch can't be run as root.

Comment: Looking at this solution, it may work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/72376209/5659278

Comment: look at this solution, it may work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72376209/5659278

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the root access to the sonar file. Try running in normal user access.

```
chown <another user>:<user group> sonar.sh
```

Comment: Changing ownership of a file has no impact on the privileges it has at runtime unless setuid is set.

Answer (score 29):

SonarSource has upgraded the Elasticsearch tool used as a part of the latest SonarQube LTS version. As a result SonarQube cannot be run as a root. See [this](https://michalwegrzyn.wordpress.com/2016/07/14/do-not-run-sonar-as-root/) blog and the [SonarQube 6.6](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+6.6+Upgrade+Notes) upgrade notes and [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46857688/getting-elasticsearch-can-not-run-as-root-error-after-upgrading-from-sonarqube) question.

Comment: Any reason why this answer was suddenly no longer accepted?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue and spend good amount of time before getting the solution.

Error was same as

```
2017.12.09 18:05:14 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap] Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:106) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:195) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
```

Solution
Create a ‘**sonar**’ user using adduser command //I was using linux system
chown -R sonar sonar-install-folder/
Edit the sonar.sh file sonar-install-folder/bin/linux-x86-6 in start script and change the #RUN_AS_USER to be RUN_AS_USER=sonar

And then use below commands

```
./sonar.sh stop
```

Gracefully stopping SonarQube...
SonarQube was not running.

```
./sonar.sh start
```

Starting SonarQube...
Started SonarQube.

```
./sonar.sh status
```

SonarQube is running (22100).

So, basically elastic search doesnt require to be run by root user. By default the RUN_AS_USER was commented in the startup script which was picking my current user which was root, and then some linux permission rules come into picture due to which elasticsearch process was not getting up and which was causing sonar process to go down as well.

It was evident from sonar.log

```
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
2020.05.08 06:36:36 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 78
2020.05.08 06:36:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2020.05.08 06:36:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a non root user only dedicated for the sonarqube instance

```
sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --group --disabled-login sonar
```

Set the permission on the sonarqube folder

```
sudo chown -R sonar:sonar /opt/sonarqube
```

Start the process

```
sudo -Hu sonar /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new user to run the sonarQube or access the SonarQube dashboard

for ubuntu flavour user creation.

#sudo adduser sonar.

after executing the above command it will ask for passwd

#adduser sonar sudo

#adduser sonar admin

#sudo su sonar

chown sonar:sonar sonar.sh

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To improve readability, please mark your code either with backticks (`\`code\``) for inline code, or by indent a code block by 4 leading spaces.
See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting for an overview of SO's Markdown formatting.

Comment: Added formatting advice