# SonarQube error running main: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.initCollisionMaps()V

Tags: java, sonarqube, continuous-integration, sonarqube-ops

Struggling to get SonarQube to run as a service. start seems to work:-

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sonar restart

Stopping SonarQube...
SonarQube was not running.
Starting SonarQube...
Started SonarQube.
```

but running status i get:-

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sonar status

SonarQube is not running.
```

looking in sonar.log i am getting the error above while loading the Wrapper:-

```
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.


WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.initCollisionMaps()V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.initCollisionMaps()V
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.reset(LoggerContext.java:222)
    at org.sonar.application.AppLogging.configure(AppLogging.java:128)
    at org.sonar.application.App.start(App.java:48)
    at org.sonar.application.App.main(App.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Earlier errors where resolved as follows

```
Encountered an error running main: org.sonar.process.MessageException: Directory must contain only one JAR file
```

(removed /opt/sonar/lib/common/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar leaving /opt/sonar/lib/common/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar)

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.re.org
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/sonar/lib/common/logback-classic-
1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/sonar/lib/common/logback-classic-
1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/sonar/lib/sonar-application-
5.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an 
explanation.r!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

(removed the 1.1.3 version and the 5.6.6 one leaving 7 in the common folder)

Not sure what i can do at this point to get the wrapper to log, any ideas?

wrapper.conf contents

```
# Path to JVM executable. By default it must be available in PATH.
# Can be an absolute path, for example:
#wrapper.java.command=/path/to/my/jdk/bin/java
wrapper.java.command=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java


#
# DO NOT EDIT THE FOLLOWING SECTIONS 
#


#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java
#********************************************************************
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dsonar.wrapped=true
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Djava.awt.headless=true
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper.java.classpath.1=/opt/sonar/lib/jsw/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=/opt/sonar/lib/common/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=/opt/sonar/lib/*.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=./lib
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.sonar.application.App
wrapper.java.initmemory=8
wrapper.java.maxmemory=32

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logs
#********************************************************************

wrapper.console.format=PM
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile=/opt/sonar/logs/sonar.log
wrapper.logfile.format=M
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=1m

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=10

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows Properties
#********************************************************************
# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=SonarQube

# Disallow start of multiple instances of an application at the same time on Windows
wrapper.single_invocation=true

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.name=SonarQube

# Display name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=SonarQube

# Description of the service
wrapper.ntservice.description=SonarQube

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false

#********************************************************************
# Forking Properties
#********************************************************************
wrapper.disable_restarts=TRUE
wrapper.ping.timeout=0
wrapper.shutdown.timeout=300
wrapper.jvm_exit.timeout=300
```

@G.Ann I believe I'm using v7.0 (sonar-application-7.0.jar) and I've renamed the version 5.6.6 version as sonar-application-5.6.6.jar.sanity

Additional:
I've played with these java libraries and noticed the sonar-application-7.0.jar file seemed tiny so gone back to using 5.6.6 I have now noticed a different error in my log as follows:

```
WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.application.AppFileSystem.<init>
(Lorg/sonar/process/Props;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.application.AppFileSystem.<init>
(Lorg/sonar/process/Props;)V
```

Google is not very forthcoming on this issue at all!

So i thought, I'll setup a new instance and see if i can get it running. I now do have SonarQube running (oddly this is not using a sonar user but the default user for this box) but it isn't loading in my browser (http://192.168.0.6:9000 remote or http://localhost:9000 on the local machine that has sonarqube installed in both cases we end with the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page (ubuntu 16.04)

looking in the new error log for this instance i get the following error:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2018.02.27 12:35:04 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /home/eclipse-creative/sonarqube-5.6.6/temp
2018.02.27 12:35:04 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/eclipse-creative/sonarqube-5.6.6/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /home/eclipse-creative/sonarqube-5.6.6/temp/sq-process1825333712376294763properties
2018.02.27 12:35:04 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
2018.02.27 12:35:04 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
2018.02.27 12:35:04 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1519734904274] version[1.7.5], pid[17427], build[00f95f4/2016-02-02T09:55:30Z]
2018.02.27 12:35:04 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1519734904274] initializing ...
2018.02.27 12:35:04 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1519734904274] loaded [], sites []
2018.02.27 12:35:04 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1519734904274] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root)]], net usable_space [191.1gb], net total_space [900.6gb], types [ext4]
2018.02.27 12:35:05 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
2018.02.27 12:35:05 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1519734904274] initialized
2018.02.27 12:35:05 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1519734904274] starting ...
2018.02.27 12:35:06 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1519734904274] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}
2018.02.27 12:35:06 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1519734904274] sonarqube/5O-W5FA2RKyVQ9mwmwS25A
2018.02.27 12:35:09 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1519734904274] new_master [sonar-1519734904274][5O-W5FA2RKyVQ9mwmwS25A][UbuntuServer6][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1519734904274}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2018.02.27 12:35:09 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1519734904274] started
2018.02.27 12:35:09 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1519734904274] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
2018.02.27 12:35:09 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2018.02.27 12:35:09 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/eclipse-creative/sonarqube-5.6.6/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/home/eclipse-creative/sonarqube-5.6.6/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /home/eclipse-creative/sonarqube-5.6.6/temp/sq-process6145003752963374984properties
2018.02.27 12:35:09 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2018.02.27 12:35:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: /home/eclipse-creative/sonarqube-5.6.6/web
2018.02.27 12:35:10 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-192.168.0.6-9000"]
2018.02.27 12:35:10 ERROR web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-192.168.0.6-9000"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:458) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:345) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:62) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:42) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:102) [sonar-process-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:68) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
2018.02.27 12:35:10 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardService] Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:345) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:62) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:42) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:102) [sonar-process-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:68) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:458) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
2018.02.27 12:35:10 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:65) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:42) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:102) ~[sonar-process-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:68) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:345) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:62) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:575) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
2018.02.27 12:35:10 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
2018.02.27 12:35:10 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2018.02.27 12:35:10 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1519734904274] stopping ...
2018.02.27 12:35:10 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1519734904274] stopped
2018.02.27 12:35:10 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1519734904274] closing ...
2018.02.27 12:35:10 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1519734904274] closed
2018.02.27 12:35:11 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I'm using apache on this instance so unsure about why tomcat is referenced. my apache conf file for sonar is:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName 192.168.0.6/sonar
    ServerAlias sonar.ecl
    ServerAdmin c.stanfield@eclipse-creative.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/sonar.ecl_access.log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/sonar.ecl_error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Not even sure if i need reverse proxy here or not really?

Here's the scenario, we have jenkins running on this box and plan to use sonar to check code during it's deploy process the server is on our work intranet and is not outward facing (bar via ssh or such) We wish to be able to view the sonar results from a failed build (notify via slack which we have working via jenkins) so the user on another machine in our network would make a request to http://192.168.0.6:9000 to access sonar and see any issues preventing the deploy. This I would imagine is how most use sonar? java is not my strongpoint coming from a c++ and php background

Craig

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the version of SonarQube you're trying to run.

Comment: Depending on the version, this may be your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731102/cant-run-sonar-server-caused-by-elasticsearch-cannot-running-as-root/47733598

Comment: Yes I'd reviewed the so question and it helped me resolve the issues on sonar.sh, I did however update the usergroup section linked on the thread but i get exactly the same error log. Ive updated my question to show version i think I'm running and I've included my wrapper.conf contents.

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that you're trying to upgrade an existing, previously working instance, by swapping around the components in the SonarQube directory?

Comment: If I'm Honest the other instance didn't work and at the time getting sonar working was less of an issue, when i returned to it months later so I found another tutorial which got a different version installed. After that errors with the db, vnc which i was able to resolve and the java issue above which I've no idea about. Would you think the best option would be too remove everything and start again or as I suspect it's that near to working that it's worth fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have tried to perform an upgrade *in situ* by selectively replacing pieces from an older version. To be clear: **that is *not* the way to upgrade**.

When you upgrade from one version to another, you should expand the zip for the new version *side-by-side* with the old version. Copy *values* from the old config file to the new one. *Maybe* copy plugins - again *from the old* version *to the new one*. Shut down the old one and spin up the new one. You'll have to tell SonarQube to upgrade its database (as described in [the Upgrade instructions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading)). And that's it.

Comment: I in essence removed the copy with 7 and 5.6.6 and moved the version in default user into /opt/sonar/ after restarting jenkins (which I noticed had stopped) sonarQube worked with configuration detailed above. Thanks G.Ann for pointing me in the right direction. I'm now able to access sonar. Just need to figure out and configure it to build with jenkins and all good. Would you recommend any tuts for working with Jenkins and Sonar (also we have a couple of projects on gitlab on the same box) from what i gather jenkins and gitlab both need a sonar plugin (which we have got on jenkins instance)

Comment: @CraigStanfield you don't _need_ a Jenkins plugin; it's provided for convenience. I'd start here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN

Comment: Thanks again I'll review this in the morning. So happy to have this running even if it is sitting idle right now!