# sonarqube.service start request repeated too quickly - Sonarqube

Tags: linux, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, azure-vm

I'm new to Linux Servers and I setup a VM to be used as a Sonarqube instance for our dev team . Everything works fine except the sonarqube service that I setup using systemctl . It gives the error as follows . However when I run the sh script Sonarqube starts up just fine .

● sonarqube.service - SonarQube service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonarqube.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-11-11 13:14:12 UTC; 1min 46s ago
Process: 1091 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/java -Xms32m -Xmx32m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar /opt/sonarqube/lib/sonar-application-8.1.0.31237.jar (code=exite
Main PID: 1091 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 11 13:14:11 recommendesonarqubeserver systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 11 13:14:11 recommendesonarqubeserver systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 11 13:14:12 recommendesonarqubeserver systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 11 13:14:12 recommendesonarqubeserver systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 11 13:14:12 recommendesonarqubeserver systemd[1]: Stopped SonarQube service.
Nov 11 13:14:12 recommendesonarqubeserver systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 11 13:14:12 recommendesonarqubeserver systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 11 13:14:12 recommendesonarqubeserver systemd[1]: Failed to start SonarQube service.

Answer (score 1):

To start SonarQube as a service, you need to have a dedicated sonarqube user say `sonar`. This `sonar`  user should own all the configuration files and other executables.

You can start the systemd service using this particular user `sonar`

Please refer to this post for more information:

[SonarQube 7.2 won't start with systemd on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673397/sonarqube-7-2-wont-start-with-systemd-on-centos-7)